# Where ARE/DO you come from?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

Which one is correct:

> Where **are** you **come** from?

or

> Where **do** you **come** from?

As we know, the first question is grammatically incorrect, but my supervisor in Egypt insists that it's right!  Could you please give me the right answer and explain why it's the right answer?

Comment: In older forms of English, *be* was a perfect auxiliary like the modern perfect auxiliary *have*.  For a long time the two coexisted, and I imagine most speakers are still aware of perfect *be*, but it's not grammatical anymore.  (It can be found in English as recent as the 19th century, though.)

Comment: @snailboat And at Christmas we still sing "Joy to the world, the Lord **is** come".

Answer (score 5):

The interrogative form of verbs in the present simple is formed with DO, not BE. "Where **do** you come from?" is therefore correct; "Where **are** you come from?" is not correct.

When BE is functioning as a main verb, DO is not used as an auxiliary for the interrogative: "Where are you from?"

When BE (or any other verb) is functioning as an auxiliary, the interrogative is formed by subject-verb inversion: "Where are you coming from?"

Answer (score 0):

> "Where **do** you come from?"

not

> "Where **are** you come from?"

You can say "Where are you?", that’s ok, but the word "come" takes "do".

Answer (score 0):

**Two possibilities:**

Where **are you from?** I **am from Argentina**.

Verb: to be + preposition + place

**Where do you come from?** I come from Argentina.

Verb: come + preposition

Verb: to come

Interrogative: do you come, does he come

"are you come" is not a grammatical form in English.